# R function that returns a string literal

Tags: string, r, statistics

I have a vector: `c(1,2,3)`

Calling `print()` on this value gives `[1] 1 2 3`

Is there a function that takes a vector and gives the string `c(1,2,3)`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `deparse`:

```
R> x <- c(1, 2, 3)
R> deparse(x)
[1] "c(1, 2, 3)"
R> class(deparse(x))
[1] "character"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I just started using R and it's pretty frustrating knowing exactly what I want to do, but not knowing what R calls it.

Answer (score 13):

using `dput`:

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3);
dput(a)
```

Comment: It worked thanks, it what one wants is the literal string: c(1, 2, 3)

Comment: if you really want it assigned to a string you need `dput(a,textConnection("x", "w"))`

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of such a function.  Perhaps you should quickly write one yourself?

```
toString <- function(a){
    output <- "c(";
    for(i in 1:(length(a)-1)){
        output <- paste(output, a[i], ",", sep="")
    }
    output <- paste(output, a[length(a)], ")\n", sep="")
    cat(output)
}
```