# Reversibly collection structure of complex R object as a string

Tags: r, parsing

I want to be able to convert a complex R object into a string, and back to the original object.

For simplicity, lets say I have a list:

```
lt <- list(a=1:10,b=data.frame(a=10, b=1:5))
lt
```

If I wanted to see this on screen, I would do the following:

```
dput(lt)
```

However, the following doesn't work:

```
x <- dput(lt)
x
x <- dput(lt,control="showAttributes")
x
```

because the value of x == lt.

I tried several things, based on previous attempts: e.g. [deparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872982/r-function-that-returns-a-string-literal/)

```
x <- deparse(lt)
x
```

works, but the reversal doesn't work:

```
eval(parse(x))
```

and the following gives an error:

```
dump(lt)
```

I am able to get it to work according to [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950084/how-to-handle-binary-strings-in-r/5950887#5950887):

```
x <- capture.output(dput(lt))
x <- paste(x,collapse="",sep="")
x

dget(textConnection(x))
```

However, I am wondering what is wrong in the first method (with eval(parse(x))).
Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Why do you want to reconstruct it?  The original object `lt` still exists.

Answer (score 3):

We have what follows:

```
lt <- list(a=1:10,b=data.frame(a=10, b=1:5))
identical(eval(parse(text=deparse(lt))), lt)
## [1] TRUE
```

Note the `text` argument setting in `parse()`.

Moreover,

```
identical(eval(dput(lt)), lt)
## structure(list(a = 1:10, b = structure(list(a = c(10, 10, 10, 
## 10, 10), b = 1:5), .Names = c("a", "b"), row.names = c(NA, -5L
## ), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("a", "b"))
## [1] TRUE
```

Here, a side effect of calling `dput()` is printing its value to the console. To disable this feature, you may e.g. redirect its output to `/dev/null` (which won't work on Windows, though).

And here's definitely the most inelegant IMHO way using `dump`:

```
f <- textConnection(NULL, open="w")
dump("lt", f)
val <- textConnectionValue(f)
close(f)
print(val)
## [1] "lt <-"                                                             
## [2] "structure(list(a = 1:10, b = structure(list(a = c(10, 10, 10, "    
## [3] "10, 10), b = 1:5), .Names = c(\"a\", \"b\"), row.names = c(NA, -5L"
## [4] "), class = \"data.frame\")), .Names = c(\"a\", \"b\"))"            
lt2 <- lt # copy
eval(parse(text=val)) # re-creates lt
identical(lt2, lt)
## [1] TRUE
```